# "moving" from the stack to the heap?

Tags: c++, c++17

I need to write a C wrapper around a C++ lib and I need objects allocated on the heap.
Functions and methods of the C++ lib use and return objects allocated on the stack.

I know, I can "transfer" an object from the stack to the heap via copy i.e. `auto heapObj = new Foo(stackObj);` but would like to avoid copy and try to `move` instead if I can.

This seems to "work" (to my surprise). Is there a copy happening behind the scenes ? If not, is this pattern safe to use ?

*main.h*

```
class Foo {
   public:
    std::vector<int> big;

    explicit Foo(size_t len);

    Foo(Foo&& other) noexcept;

    // remove copy constructor
    Foo(const Foo &) = delete;

    // delete assignment operator
    Foo &operator=(const Foo &) = delete;


    size_t size();
};
```

*main.cpp*

```
#include <iostream>
#include "main.h"

Foo::Foo(size_t len) : big(len) {}

Foo::Foo(Foo&& other) noexcept : big(std::move(other.big)) {}

size_t Foo::size() { return this->big.size(); }

int main() {
    Foo ms(1000);  // on the stack
    ms.big[0] = 42;

    auto mh = new Foo(std::move(ms));  // on the heap (no copy?)

    std::cout << mh->size() << ", " << mh->big[0] << std::endl;

    delete mh;
}
```

Comment: If you `= delete` the copy constructor and copy assignment operator you don't have to worry about secret copies being made. The compiler will complain if one where ever to occur.

Comment: If you provide a move constructor you probably need to provide a move assignment operator. This is part of the rule of [3/5/0](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three). Though in this case you can just use the compiler provided one.

Comment: The data in `big` is never on the stack to begin with. The part that is on the stack is copied, of course. I am not quite sure what's unclear here tbh.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Done. No changes (it is the copy of the vector that worries me though)

Comment: @BrunoGrieder If `Foo` isn't copied, then neither are it's members.

Comment: "but would like to avoid copy and try to move instead if I can" isn't moving just copying + deleting (or simply ignoring) original?

Comment: @BaummitAugen OK. Got it. the content of the `big`member is on the heap. hence, this is OK

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca Maybe for some types like `std::array` but for most containers it copies the internal state of that container (ex. the pointer to the data and size) and zeroes out the original container. The actual data is left in place. Edit : Even for hard to move containers like `std::array` it would move each element, so for example moving an `std::array` of `std::vector` would still not just be copying/clearing.

Comment: @BrunoGrieder Basically `Foo(Foo&& other) noexcept;`, This constuctor will be called. Whether it is copied or not depends on how you implement it. If you mark it as `default`, then `vector's` move constructor will be called which will just copy a pointer

Comment: Generally speaking, writing a C wrapper does not require putting objects on the heap. If the C wrapper takes pointers, you can pass the address of an object, regardless of whether that object is on the heap or the stack.

Comment: @PeteBecker Ha. Interesting. Say I have a function returning  an rValue (say `Foo createFoo()`), I dereference that and pass it (return it) to a python wrapper. What happens next ?

Comment: @BrunoGrieder -- it depends on the details. One possibility is `Foo f = createFoo(); call_whatever(&f);`. Again: **generally speaking** you don't need to move things around. That, of course, means that there may be situations where you need to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, moving an `int` or a pointer is equivalent to a copy. That is, if you had a

```
struct X {
  int a, b;
  int* data;
};
```

then moving it is not going to be cheaper than copying it (ignoring ownership of `data` for now). Coincidentally, the above is basically what `std::vector` looks like from far away: A `size` and `capacity` member plus some pointer to a chunk of memory.

The important thing about **moving vs copying** is what happens in regards to **ownership of resources**. `std::vector` has ownership of some heap memory (`data`). If you **copy** a `std::vector`, that heap memory must be copied, so that both the original and the copy can have ownership of their own data. But if you **move** it, then only the moved-to vector needs to retain ownership, so the `data` pointer can be handed from one to the other (instead of all the data), because the ownership can be "stolen" from the moved-from object.

This is why there is no conflict in "moving" your object from the stack to the heap: The object itself is still basically copied from one place to the other, but the resources it (or its subobjects, like `big`) owns are not copied but moved ("stolen").

Comment: Txs. made it a small TLDR at the beginning of the post

Comment: @BrunoGrieder I removed it. Answers don't go in the question :)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit OK; the premise in the question is false; I just want to avoid an unnecessary read to the next reader

Comment: @BrunoGrieder A reader unwilling to read is not a reader and can be safely ignored :P

Comment: @BrunoGrieder when reading the question I expect it to have wrong code, false premises etc, if on top of that it contains an attempt to answer I get completely confused ;)

Answer (score 1):

Any time a move "actually happens", it's because there is some *indirect resource* within the moved thing. Some resource that's referred to by a handle that can be cheaply swapped (a pointer copied over, for example; the pointee remains where it was). This is generally accomplished via pointers to dynamically-allocated things, such as the data stored within a vector.

The stuff you're trying to move is a vector. As such, *it is already dynamically-allocated* and the move is easy. It doesn't really matter where the actual `std::vector` object lives, nor where the `Foo` lives — if there's an indirect resource, a move is probably possible.

In other cases, a move constructor or move assignment will actually just trigger a copy of whatever data is inside. When everything (recursively) in the "thing" has automatic storage duration, you can pretty much guarantee that a copy will be required. But that's not the case here.